# ADO.Net in Asp.Net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When I use connection string builder in an ASP.Net 5 application I get this error:

> Error CS0012  The type 'DbConnectionStringBuilder' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I'm using dnx451 as the framework, any sugestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example project.json

```
"frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
```