# Could not get reference of System.Data in Asp.Net 5

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, system.data

I am building an web application using ASP.NET5 MVC6 and Classic Ado.Net. 
But we could not take reference of System.Data. Only two packages are available in nuget packages

```
System.Data.Common and System.Data.SqlClient.
```

In addition to that, whenever I add System.Data.Common from nuget, my project is not compiling.

I need DataSet and Datatable in the controller's action method.

How could we get this in Asp.Net 5 ?

> I have got answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415928/ado-net-in-asp-net-5).

Answer (score 0):

The current version of System.Data.Common and System.Data.SqlClient. are conflicting with other asp.net-5 libraries.

You can use EF7 and use the connection object from the DBConect.Database

```
        var conn = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
        var cmd=conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1";
        conn.Open();
        var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: I have added "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta8" in project.json. But var conn = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection(); creates error.

Comment: See web template how to setup a DBContext. you need first initialize EF7 with a connectionstring